# Ruby Koans Proxy Project

Tags: ruby

I'm walking through the Ruby Koans and I have a trouble in `about_proxy_object_project.rb`
This is my solution

```
class Proxy
  attr_reader :messages

  def initialize(target_object)
    @object = target_object
    # ADD MORE CODE HERE
    @messages = []
  end

  def number_of_times_called(method_name)
    @messages.count method_name
  end

  def called?(method_name)
    @messages.include? method_name
  end 

  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    if @object.respond_to? method_name  
      @object.send(method_name, *args)
      @messages << method_name
    else
      super method_name, *args, &block
    end
  end
end
```

but when I typed `rake` I got this

```
The answers you seek...
  Expected 10 to equal [:channel=, :power, :channel]

Please meditate on the following code:
  /home/Shanicky/koans/about_proxy_object_project.rb:61:in `test_tv_methods_still_perform_their_function'
```

and in my `about_proxy_object_project.rb`

```
def test_tv_methods_still_perform_their_function
  tv = Proxy.new(Television.new)

  tv.channel = 10
  tv.power

  assert_equal 10, tv.channel # this is the 61st line
  assert tv.on?
end
```

I am confused
Where i did do wrong?
Thanks all

and this is my `Television` class

```
class Television
  attr_accessor :channel

  def power
    if @power == :on
      @power = :off
    else
      @power = :on
    end
  end

  def on?
    @power == :on
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't modify any method in Television class before,so I think the channel method should return 10 ,but it seems that it returns an array like [:channel=, :power, :channel] , so I'm confused

Comment: Can you post the definition of the `Television` class?

Comment: @Agis thank you, I've modified the question and posted the definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this `if` clause:

```
if @object.respond_to? method_name  
  @object.send(method_name, *args)
  @messages << method_name # <-- this is the return value you get
else
  super method_name, *args, &block
end
```

The check `@object.respond_to? method_name` always evaluates to `true` because the `Television` class defines all these methods you've called on its objects (`channel=`, `power`, `channel`). Therefore the first branch of the `if` runs and this code essentially adds to the `@messages` instance variable (which is an `Array`) the method names that you are calling.

So when you call `tv.channel` the return value of the method is that commented statement in the above code, which of course is not equal to `10`. You essentially get the return value of `@messages << method_name` which is the new `@messages` array, which actually contains all the undefined method you've called until that time: `[:channel=, :power, :channel]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use 'send' without checking. There is no purpose of using 'else' because it always returns some Exception.

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
  @messages << method_name
  @object.send(method_name, *args, &block)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you swap the two statements:
@object.send(method_name, *args)
@messages << method_name # <-- this is the return value you get

so:
@messages << method_name # <-- this is the return value you get
@object.send(method_name, *args)

then the return value would be whatever is returned by the method_name, and so in the case of tv.channel it would return 10 as expected in your test.

I think this is just saying the same thing as in the answer, but thought it worth making it clearer